# Debugging PHP script in Intellij Idea

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea, ide, xdebug

I am trying to break in the first line of my PHP script to step over line by line but my IDE seems to be trying to connect to local server. Its a simple standalone script which I want to execute line by line . Following is the console output

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 RandomTest.php
```

Do I have to turn of xdebug.remote_enable in php.ini or there is a way to override  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows try:

```
set XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM...OTHER XDEBUG SETTINGS..."
```

To set the session, which looks for the connection.
Then you should just be able to run your script and it should work!

Comment: I am actually on a Mac. So you mean I can ignore the connection ? Its running the script but I wanted it to stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: It should be the same really (export instead of set)

export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM remote_enable=1 remote_mode=req remote_port=9000 remote_host=127.0.0.1"

This will set the config for your current terminal session - so when you run 

/usr/bin/php RandomTest.php

It should use those xdebug settings.

idekey should be the one for your IDE (not sure the one for intellij, but a quick google has suggested "intellij" ) and make sure you have the debug listener switched on in the IDE.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also if this doesn't work - have you got xdebug set up correctly in your php.ini? You may have a different conf for php-cli and the web version of php?

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help out. I gave a thumbs up. It turns out to be that the Xdebug was not properly configured , I will answer the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out after several hours of investigation that the XDebug was not simple configured correctly.

Finally checked various config files (like php.ini or /usr/local/etc/php/5.3/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini ) which are getting loaded , you may want to put  zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php53-xdebug/2.2.6/xdebug.so if you have installed xdebug via macports

Ran the following to know if Xdebug was not loaded. It gave me loading error initially but after editing ini files I got following .

```
➜  ~  php -v
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Jan 23 2015 12:47:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

[image: Conformation of Xdebug installation in IDE]